# Code inside of "foreach" being skipped C#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach, skip

I have "foreach" nested inside of "for". The program goes like this: It goes through the "for" on to the "foreach" and skips the code inside of "foreach" and goes back to "for". Does anyone know why is it doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to post the code

Comment: That happens if the variable you're iterating over is empty.

Comment: Without code to look at, just guesses here. Do you have a semicolon on the same _for_ line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason a `foreach` is "skipped" is because the sequence being iterated it empty, i.e. `GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` is returning `false`.